# (WCF Service) Toggle on/off discovery endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-discovery, webservice-discovery

I'm developing a simple WCF-based application.

My service is very simple, just 2 endpoints:
1) The service
2) updDiscovery

```
<services>
    <service name="myService">
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.18/service"/>
        <endpoint name="udpDiscovery" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="adhocDiscoveryEndpointConfiguration"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

It works great but I'd toggle on/off the discoverability of my service. 
I tried to change the Enable parameter but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Cheers
Mauro

Answer (score 0):

Add a behaviousConfiguration to your udpDiscovery end-point. Within the behaviour, put `<endpointDiscovery enabled="false"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this solution but I can't turn it on. I'd like turn it on/off programmatically. Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.udpannouncementendpoint.aspx - It has a facility to add behaviourConfiguration. Could you try doing it programatically. Not sure if that helps